# Deploy webapp from git to Azure with CI

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I want to deploy the project code from the local git to Azure using CI.

So when push the code on the git, it will merge on the Azure Ubuntu VM server by CI.
Please share the experience if you have. 
Thank you

Comment: What does merge on VM? Could you express more about that? In addition, does CI you mentioned point to azure devops pipeline?

Comment: @Merlin Thanks for your response. I am going to merge the php symfony and react code from local git to Azure VM server. I didn't mention about the azure devops pipline. I am not sure which cI is good for this. 
Please let me know if you have experience. 
Thank you